# Getting "invalid type argument of '->' (have 'int')" while trying to use a txt file in functions

Tags: c, function, pointers, int

I have to get the code I made for opening a txt file and counting the words in functions but am having problems with properly moving text file around (I'm pretty sure).

I've tried googling on how to return a file in c, obviously this error and I had some errors after trial and error about invalid type argument of unary. I'm not good with programming but before I switch to a different electrical engineering path I have to finish some programming assignments for signoff and this one in particular I have an aweful lot of trouble with.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char openIt();
int countIt(char (*p_file));

int main()
{
    int wordCount = countIt(openIt());
}

char openIt(void)
{
    FILE * p_file = fopen("alice-ch1.txt", "r");
    return p_file;
}

int countIt(char (*p_file))
{
    int wordcount = 0;
    int i = 0;

    if (p_file == NULL)
    {
        printf("File cannot be opened!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        char tempChar;
        char chapter[16383];
        int i;
        int wordcount = 0;
        int filed = fgetc(p_file);
        while (!feof(*p_file))   //this is where the error occurs
        {
            for(i = 0; !feof(*p_file); i++)
            {
                tempChar = getc(p_file);
                chapter[i] = tempChar;

                if(chapter[i] == ' ' || chapter[i] == '\n')
                {
                    if((chapter[i-1] != ' ' || chapter[i-2] != ' ') && chapter[i-1] != '*' && chapter[i-1] != '\n')
                    {
                        wordcount++;   // ((chapter[i-1] <= 'A' && chapter[i-1] >= 'Z') || (chapter[i-1] <= 'a' && chapter[i-1] >= 'z'))
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        fclose(p_file);
    }
}
```

I expect it to the count the words in a given text file but am getting the error message from the title

Comment: The function return value and hence the argument passed must be of type `FILE *`. Also please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) You are also using `!feof(*p_file);` as a loop condition. Have a look at [`feof` man page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/feof?view=vs-2017) to see what it does. Also enable all compiler warnings and see what they tell you.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the wrong return type on this function

```
char openIt(void)
{
    FILE * p_file = fopen("alice-ch1.txt", "r");
    return p_file;
}
```

`p_file` is a pointer to `FILE` (`FILE *`) so that should be the data type used as the return value as well.

And then you're passing the return value from that function to `countIt`...but that doesn't take a `FILE *` as it's only parameter either. Which is what the various functions that operate on files (ie `fgetc`) are expecting. This is where the specific error your question refers to comes from as you're de-referencing `p_file` so it is no longer a pointer.

I would be very surprised if your compiler didn't throw up a load of errors and warnings with such code.

You should change the function definitions to be as follows.

```
FILE *openIt(void)

int countIt(FILE *p_file)
```